# n:1 to two n:1, is this table normalized properly?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, relational-database, database-normalization

thank you for your attention. It's been a while since I learned normalization in school and university and if you go work in the industries, you will find that often these theoretic things might interfere with what you boss tells you to do. So here is an example of something I'm thinking about for a while and I would love to hear your oppinion. I'm not even sure if there is a right or wrong on this approach so every answer is welcome.

Scenario:
We are developing a person management system (PMS). For this, we have a Person table, to store generic information about each person (e. g. Name), a Country table, to store the native country of a person and a Race table for the persons race.

Therefore you could have two foreign key columns on Person, linking to Country and Race, right?

However, my boss want's me to use a fourth table. Lets call it PersonType. The PersonType consists of a primary key as well as the foreign keys colums to Country and Race. The Person table then only has one foreign key column to PersonType.

Therefore I would have a n:1 relation between Person and PersonType as well as n:1 relations between PersonType and Country/Race, right?

In my opinion, the PersonType table is not necessary because you could just put the foreign key columns directly on the Person table but my boss argues that the PersonType can be used to constrain which Country/Race combinations are valid. I understand that argument but I'm asking myself if this database is still properly normalized.

(Of course we are not really developing a PMS but I thought it's easy to imagine and I can't talk about what we are really developing due to an NDA).

**UPDATE 21/10/2016**

Heres how the table structure looks like in an abstract way:

```
table person_v1(
  person_id int primarykey,
  name string,
  country_id int foreignkey(country),
  race_id int foreignkey(race)
)

table person_v2(
  person_id int primarykey,
  name string,
  person_type_id int foreignkey(person_type)
)

table person_type(
  person_type_id int primarykey,
  country_id int foreignkey(country),
  race_id int foreignkey(race)
)

table country(
  country_id int primarykey,
  name string
)

table race(
  race_id int primarykey,
  name string
)
```

Thank you for your answers so far

Comment: *"The Person table then only has one foreign key column to PersonType."* Only if you introduce a new attribute, like person_type_id, and some new functional dependencies. Doing *that* isn't normalization; that's using surrogate keys. (Surrogate keys have to do with data compression, not normalization.) Normalization doesn't introduce new attributes. I think a relation person_type {country_code, race_code}, having the single candidate key (country_code, race_code), is already in 5NF.

Comment: *"my boss argues that the PersonType can be used to constrain which Country/Race combinations are valid"* That's true. And if enforcing that constraint is a requirement, then you need that fourth table. But there really *aren't* any invalid combinations of native country and race. No idea whether that applies to your actual situation.

Comment: *"there really aren't any invalid combinations of native country and race"* you are right. Basically there aren't invalid combinations. It's more of a business rule/logic and in my opinion could be implemented otherwise. Currentyl our init scrips create the entries in "person_type" but nothing stops me from creating additional entries up to the maximum of possible entries (which is count(countries) * count(races))

Comment: @xxtesaxx Actually you can create many. many more rows in the `person_type` table because you can add the same `{ country_id, race_id }` combination over and over again, as long as you have a different `person_type_id` each time, and end up with real life duplicates. Obviously you can prevent this by making `{ country_id, race_id }` a key. Because the absolute number of countries and their races are small, I can't see any advantage to using the surrogate key `person_type_id`.

Comment: ...actually you can repeatedly add `{ country_id = null, race_id = null } over and over again, and you end up with effectively no data! So you have some basic data integrity issues.

Comment: @onedaywhen thanks, I think actually there should be a constraint on person_type which would prevent duplicated with the same country_id and race_id but currently there isn't so I'll bring this to discussion. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of 1:N or M:N relationships doesn't determine a relation's normal form. The question actually has nothing to do with normalization.

Some tables . . .

**Your design**

Follow standards when you can. 
For countries, I'll follow ISO 3166-1.

```
create table countries (
  iso_country_code char(3) primary key,
  country_name varchar(75) not null unique
);

insert into countries (iso_country_code, country_name) values
('USA', 'United States of America'),
('GBR', 'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland'),
('MKD', 'Macedonia (the former Yugoslav Republic of)'),
('ZZZ', 'Unknown country'); -- 'ZZZ' is reserved for a user-assigned value.
```

For race, I'll follow CDC/HL7 race codes.
There are other standards. 
One of them might be more appropriate. 
See http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/dvs/race_ethnicity_codeset.pdf

Most applications allow multiple race codes for each person. 
I'm ignoring that real-world fact for *this* question.

```
create table races (
  cdc_unique_id char(6) primary key,
  cdc_race_concept varchar(50) not null unique
);

insert into races (cdc_unique_id, cdc_race_concept) values
('2056-0', 'Black'),
('2106-3', 'White'),
('2076-8', 'Native Hawaiian or other Pacific islander'),
('zzzz-z', 'Unknown');

create table persons (
  person_id integer primary key,
  person_full_name varchar(25) not null,
  iso_country_code char(2) not null 
    default 'ZZZ' 
    references countries (iso_country_code)
      on update cascade
      on delete set default,
  cdc_unique_id char(6) not null
    default 'zzzz-z'
    references races (cdc_unique_id)
      on update cascade
      on delete set default
);
```

All three of these tables are in at least 5NF.

One potential problem with your design 
is that it allows arbitrary parings
of country and race. 
Imagine that, instead of country and race, 
we were talking about city and state in the USA.
An arbitrary paring of city and state would allow
"San Francisco, AL". 
But there is no city named "San Francisco" in Alabama.

That's why allowing arbitrary parings might be a bad decision.

**Your boss's design**

```
-- The same as the table above.
create table countries (
  iso_country_code char(3) primary key,
  country_name varchar(75) not null unique
);

insert into countries (iso_country_code, country_name) values
('USA', 'United States of America'),
('GBR', 'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland'),
('MKD', 'Macedonia (the former Yugoslav Republic of)'),
('ZZZ', 'Unknown country'); -- 'ZZZ' is reserved for a user-assigned value.

-- Also the same as the table above.
create table races (
  cdc_unique_id char(6) primary key,
  cdc_race_concept varchar(50) not null unique
);

insert into races (cdc_unique_id, cdc_race_concept) values
('2056-0', 'Black'),
('2106-3', 'White'),
('2076-8', 'Native Hawaiian or other Pacific islander'),
('zzzz-z', 'Unknown');

-- This table is new.
create table person_types (
  iso_country_code char(3) not null
    default 'ZZZ'
    references countries (iso_country_code)
      on update cascade
      on delete set default,
  cdc_unique_id char(6) not null
    default 'zzzz-z'
    references races (cdc_unique_id)
      on update cascade
      on delete set default,
  primary key (iso_country_code, cdc_unique_id)
);

insert into person_types values
('USA', '2016-3'),
('USA', '2056-0'),
('GBR', '2016-3'),
('GBR', '2056-0'),
```

This "person_types" table records a fact 
that *your* database design does not. 
It records the fact 
that white persons and black persons 
might be native to both the USA and to Great Britain.
If recording that fact is important, you *must* include "person_types".

Also, it's worth noting that this table is immune to the problems cited in other comments; you cannot repeatedly add rows where both iso_country_code and cdc_unique_id are null (`not null` constraint), you cannot duplicate iso_country_code and cdc_unique_id (`primary key` constraint), etc.

Conceptually, you decide which facts to store before you normalize. Normalization can't help you with attributes that don't exist in your schema. That's a different database design task.

```
-- Structurally identical to the table above.
-- Constraints are slightly different.
--
create table persons (
  person_id integer primary key,
  person_full_name varchar(25) not null,
  iso_country_code char(2) not null
    default 'ZZZ',
  cdc_unique_id char(6) not null
    default 'zzzz-z',
  constraint person_types_fk foreign key (iso_country_code, cdc_unique_id)
    references person_types (iso_country_code, cdc_unique_id)
      on update cascade
      on delete set default
);
```

All four of these tables are in at least 5NF.

The difference is not that one set of tables is more normalized than the other.

The difference is that **one set of tables records a fact that the other does not**.

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this table is common to both yours and your boss's designs:

```
CREATE TABLE RaceMeetings
( country_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  race_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE ( country_name, race_name ) );
```

From what I can tell, your design is this (one table):

```
CREATE TABLE People_v1
( person_name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
  country_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  race_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY ( country_name, race_name )
     REFERENCES RaceMeetings ( country_name, race_name ) );
```

...and you boss's design is this (two tables):

```
CREATE TABLE People_v2
( person_name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL UNIQUE );

CREATE TABLE RaceMeetingAttendance
( person_name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL UNIQUE
     REFERENCES People_v2 ( person_name ),
  country_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  race_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY ( country_name, race_name )
     REFERENCES RaceMeetings ( country_name, race_name ) );
```

Both designs

- are fully normalized
- are in 5NF
- restrict { country_name, race_name } combination for a person to be defined in table `RaceMeetings`.

Your boss's design is additionally in 6NF but that does not necessarily confer any practical advantage.

However, I do prefer your boss's design based on the rule of thumb that a table should model either an entity or a relationship between entities but never both. Put another way, a race meeting such as "The race 'Pacific Grand Prix' is held in Japan" doesn't strike me as being an attribute of a person. It seem to me more like a relationship (a correspondence from person to race meeting) and using a separate table to model this relationship allows me to usefully give it the name `RaceMeetingAttendance'.

That said, your design has the advantage that a person who hasn't attended a race meeting cannot exist in your database, should that be a requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I updated my original post to give you a better understanding of our database structure, could you have a look at it? I'd highly appreciate your opinion. Thanks, Jan